# Laravel, seemingly complex eloquent relationships

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I am really having some issues getting my head around this, but, I'll try to explain what it is that I want to achieve and hopefully one of you can point me in the right direction.

I have a `Role` entity, nothing crazy here just a name field.

I also have a `RoleField` entity, this is used to basically build forms and will contain information like, `field_type`.

A user can assign themselves a `Role` so I have a table `user_roles`, but a user can also have answers to the form that was built using the `RoleField` entity. This is the bit that is giving me headaches.

Some of this might be a matter of opinion and I know that this place isn't meant for opinions but there is also some hard answers in there somewhere.

So firstly, what is the optimal database structure for a scenario that a user has the ability to save answers to their role. What would these relationships look like? Should I structure my endpoints to be `user/1/role/1/field/1/answer` seems rather long winded?

Comment: What does your database structure look like? What is the relationship between `Role` and `RoleField`?

Comment: This is completely open but at the moment I have a roles, role_fields & user_roles the issue is what to do with the answers, new table? user_fields_answers? What would the relationships look like?

Comment: Without more information it's hard to say. What is an "answer"? Can the data be normalized or is it abstract? Can you provide a specific example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: A role has fields, for example, description which gets rendered as text area. The user can then input data into the form and submit and there I can imagine for the answers I would need user_id, role_field_id, value , I can then maybe call to get a field and associated answer will be returned for that user as well.

Comment: For your example of a role description, why would you store it as an `answer` in some other table instead of as a `description` field directly in the `roles` table?

Comment: Because the roles and fields are generic whereas the answers (description) is for the user only.

Comment: Imagine this being a survey, you have surveys, questions, questions fields and then the users answers.

Comment: In fact that has given me something to Google. Rubber ducking ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181572/discussion-between-ben-harold-and-chrisbratherton).

Comment: Sorry, getting late, going to pick this up again in the morning. At least I have something to Google now. Thanks for the nudge :)